# copy images issue in php

Tags: php, copy

I want to copy some images from one folder to another, I do not want to copy them all.
Here is my code but it give me an issue `failed to open stream`

```
$image = "a.jpg";
$srcfile='uploads/listings/my_from/'.$image;
$dstfile='uploads/listings/my_to/images/';

copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
```

What am I missing? Can I do anyhting else so that I can copy selected images to destination without deleting it?

Note: both of these folders are on the same server and same project. Should I do it by curl?

Comment: And you're _sure_ `a.jpg` exists, in `uploads/listings/my_from/`?

Comment: I would not use curl if the images are on the same server tho ?
PHP has a copy function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: $dstfile gives you a path, but not a file name. Try: `$dstfile="uploads/listings/my_to/images/$image";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might pay to do some error checking as well, but you just need to add the full image path to your `$dstfile` variable:

```
<?php

$image = "a.jpg";
$srcfile='uploads/listings/my_from/'.$image;
$dstfile='uploads/listings/my_to/images/'.$image;

echo 'Attempting to copy "'.$srcfile.'" to "'.$dstfile.'"<br />';

if(file_exists($srcfile)) {
    if(file_exists($dstfile)) {
        echo 'Cannot copy file, destination file already exists';
    } else {
        if(is_writable(dirname($dstfile))) {
            if(copy($srcfile,$dstfile)) {
                echo 'File successfully copied';
            } else {
                echo 'File could not be copied';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Destination is not writable';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Cannot copy file, source file doesnt exist';
}
?>
```

Comment: $srcfile='http://localhost/crm/uploads/listings/shaf_from/30273437WaterWinter.jpg';
    $dstfile='http://localhost/crm/uploads/listings/shaf_to/images/30273437WaterWinter.jpg';..here $dstfile give me same issue

Comment: give me "Cannot copy file, source file doesnt exist",although it hs image,when i run link in url,it shows image

Comment: I've made an edit (the `echo` linue under the variable declarations). Could you post the output of the script when you run it now?

Comment: Ahh, I see, you will need to specify the image relative to the PHP script rather than use the URL the image is accessible from.

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that file `a.jpg` exists, then this should work

```
$srcfile='uploads/listings/my_from/'.$image;
$dstfile='uploads/listings/my_to/images/'.$image;

copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
```

note: destination file name must be specified.

Comment: when i run path in url,it shows image,but code give me same issue again

Answer (score 1):

You should check it exists really.

try:

```
$image = "a.jpg";
$srcfile='uploads/listings/my_from/'. $image;
$dstfile='uploads/listings/my_to/images/' . $image;

if(!file_exists($srcfile) {
    throw new \Exception("File does not exist!");
}

copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
```